# Cannot install react-paypal-button-v2

Tags: reactjs, npm, paypal, dependencies

I'm following an e-commerce tutorial and unlike the instructor I cannot install [react-paypal-button-v2](https://github.com/Luehang/react-paypal-button-v2).

My error log is

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x" from react-paypal-button-v2@2.6.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-paypal-button-v2
npm ERR!   react-paypal-button-v2@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

And in case it helps, this is my package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
        "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm puzzled because I have exactly the same dependency tree as the instructor, the only differences being that I installed `moment` and `dotenv` and that he runs on a PC and I'm on a Mac, but he installs it without issues.

The tutorial is very recent (less than a month old) and the versions in his package.json are basically the same as in mine.

I found this open [issue](https://github.com/Luehang/react-paypal-button-v2/issues/89), but it hasn't been addressed by the developers.

I would love to know how to go around this issue and carry on, and I'm sure it will also help me in the future on how to sort these errors.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use **forcefully** install by using `--force` in the end of you command.

```bash
npm install react-paypal-button-v2 --force
```

Comment: I got `--legacy-peer-deps` to work instead, also.

Answer (score 1):

this is an issue with the npm. you can install it with yarn it will work fine.

```
yarn add react-paypal-button-v2
```

yarn installation [steps](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable)

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this before and while it installs, the installer mentions there's a wrong dependency tree.   I also noticed that the latest release from the package (2.6.2) is from April 2020 and that its package.json uses React v 16.8.2 as dependency. I've been using npm so far and wonder if switching to yarn will cause future issues or if I need to yarn the whole project again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this library is usually related to compatibility with `React` version. Please check with this if you encounter compatibility issues.

```
npm install react-paypal-button-v2 --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also answered with another way, As you can see in your **error**. It is a **dependency conflict** between the version. According to the error, `react-paypal-button-v2` has a **peer dependency**.

Which means:

> It expects a specific version or range of versions.

As you can see, your package has **peer dependency** on `Reactjs`.

```js
peer react@"^0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x
```

So, changing the version may helpful. About your error, it said `0.14.6 || 15.x.x || 16.x.x`. In that all range version of React are acceptable or compatible with your package, but it may not be compatible with React versions `17.x.x` or higher according to your error.